# C++ Clang VSCode project not registering precompiled header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, clang++

I have an issue in my C++ project where the items in my precompiled header are not being picked up by the C/C++ extension in VSCode's intellisense. Here is my following project structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    └── precompiled.h
```

And here are the individual files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(MyApp)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(PRECOMPILED_HEADER "src/precompiled.h")

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PRECOMPILED_HEADER})
```

src/main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

src/precompiled.h:

```
#ifndef PRECOMPILED_H
#define PRECOMPILED_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#endif // PRECOMPILED_H
```

I can build this project and run it fine, but I can't seem to get VSCode's intellisense to understand the inclusion of the precompiled header in the source files, as I'm getting red squiggles in my main under `std` and `cout`, `use of undeclared identifier 'std'C/C++(clang-diagnostic-error)` and `namespace "std" has no member "cout"C/C++(135)`. This is even after the `compile_commands.json` file has been generated and read.

I have tried to use `forceInclude` which is a C/C++ extension setting to force include the precompiled header to all files, which kind of works, however the precompiled header is specific to a smaller project amongst the entire project so it shouldn't be included to every file.

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance on this? Thanks!

I tried using forceInclude setting in the C/C++ extension in vscode, but this does not exactly do as expected. I also tried to play around with the other configurations in this settings but could not find a solution that way either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `target_precompile_headers` is to _create_ the pre-compiled header- not to register an already created one. I don't know if it works for an existing one.